# Where do I save my files when I create a plugin in zend?

Tags: zend-framework

This is probably the most frustrating part for newbies learning about zend.

Where do I create my new class' file?

There's an exemple here:
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=4988

or another one here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

But none of them mention where this plugin should be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best idea is to put your classes where the autoloader can find them. It's also a pseudo-convention to mimic the Zend class name structure.

For example, say you've made a controller plugin named "Foo". Name the class

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_Foo extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
```

and save the file at `library/My/Controller/Plugin/Foo.php`.

To have the autoloader pick up your "My" namespace (note, this isn't a PHP 5.3 namespace), simply add this to your `application.ini` file

```
autoloaderNamespaces.My = "My_"
```

The only restriction here is that your "My" folder must be in the include path. Putting it in the "library" folder solves this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I like the _autoload mechanism a lot. I'll go with that.

Comment: I guess ZF screwed big way changing the proven autoloading schema (libraries in /library, models in /models) with extremly-hard-to-understand App_Model_Rubbish stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify your plugin directory in your **application.ini** file

```
resources.frontController.plugindirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/plugins"
```

or

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
resources.frontController.plugins.MyPlugin = 
                          "My_Controller_Plugin_MyPlugin"
```

this assumes you have

```
/path/to/library/My/Controller/Plugin/MyPlugin.php
```

Learn more about [**Application's Directory Layout**](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Choosing+Your+Application%27s+Directory+Layout) in zend framework.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the link to solve them all! I was looking for some general rule to apply to my newly created classes without success. There should be more echo on the web about it.